# Swing layout problem

Tags: java, swing, layout

I'm lost in the Swing laying out nightmare :( I'm going to expose my problem, but I'm looking for advices as well as the clear solution.

My problem : I want to design a form like this :

[image]

And I'm struggling with the code generated by Netbeans :

```
private void initComponents() {

    buttonGroup1 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    buttonGroup2 = new javax.swing.ButtonGroup();
    jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
    jRadioButton1 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jRadioButton2 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
    jRadioButton3 = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(200, 200));

    jPanel1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(400, 44));
    jPanel1.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(jPanel1, javax.swing.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    jPanel2.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new java.awt.Color(0, 255, 255)));
    jPanel2.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(11111111, 2147483647));
    jPanel2.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(jPanel2, javax.swing.BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Grande", 0, 48)); // NOI18N
    jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");
    jTextField1.setAlignmentY(0.0F);
    jTextField1.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(150, 2147483647));
    jTextField1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 42));
    jPanel2.add(jTextField1);

    jTextField2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Lucida Grande", 0, 8)); // NOI18N
    jTextField2.setText("jTextField2");
    jTextField2.setAlignmentY(0.0F);
    jTextField2.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(150, 2147483647));
    jTextField2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(100, 28));
    jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });
    jPanel2.add(jTextField2);

    jPanel1.add(jPanel2);

    jPanel3.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 51));
    jPanel3.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(jPanel3, javax.swing.BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));

    jPanel4.setLayout(new javax.swing.BoxLayout(jPanel4, javax.swing.BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    jRadioButton1.setText("jRadioButton1");
    jPanel4.add(jRadioButton1);

    jRadioButton2.setText("jRadioButton2");
    jPanel4.add(jRadioButton2);

    jRadioButton3.setText("jRadioButton3");
    jPanel4.add(jRadioButton3);

    jPanel3.add(jPanel4);

    jPanel1.add(jPanel3);

    getContentPane().add(jPanel1, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);

    pack();
}
```

Something I really don't get is that when I change the layout of jPanel3, ther is a change in the rendering of jPanel2 !

Can someone give me a howto path to follow ?

Comment: someone is going to recommend MigLayout anyway and that 'someone' happens to be me

Comment: "when I change the latout of jPanel3, ther is a change in the rendering of jPanel2 !" - how are you changing the layout of jPanel3 ? using the GUIBuilder or manually? If manually, try using the guibuilder to achieve this.

Comment: A good rule of thumb of swing layout, nowadays, is to avoid using too many embedded panels but rather use more powerful LayoutManagers on just one panel. There are several such LayoutManagers: GroupLayout (complex API), DesignGridLayout, MigLayout, TableLayout...

Comment: I take good point to GroupLayout and GridBag. I'm going to test them before writing a response.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using a [GridBagLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) because it gives you the best control over where components are located and how much space they take up.

For instance, to make JPanel 2 and 3 fill up your content pane you would do:

```
GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
JPanel jPanel1 = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
jPanel1.add(jPanel2, constraints);
constraints.gridy ++;
jPanel1.add(jPanel2, constraints);
```

Also, if you want your Swing code to be understandable when you return to it several days later you will want to break it up into functions and use more descriptive variable names, such as "topTextPanel" and "middleButtonPanel".

Comment: why this answer was down-voted, I missed here any logical reason, that pretty possible, hmmm :-) since I'd be using some of infinite number of variations from `Nested Layout` :-)

Comment: I personally am a huge fan of `GridBagLayout` and `GridBagConstraints`. I would highly recommend them for pretty much ANY swing GUI apart from a basic dialog. You literally can do anything with them, and its all very easy once you get the hang of it.

Comment: Yeah, I personally use the Facade Pattern to reduce the verbosity of using JPanel and the GridBagConstraints together.  The whole layout API for Swing is pretty painful to use by itself.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that could be a starting point using BoxLayout:

```
JPanel panel1= new JPanel();
panel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel1, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

JPanel panel2= new JPanel();
panel2.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel2, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
panel2.setMinimumSize(...); panel2.setMaximumSize(...) ; panel2.setPreferredSize(...);

JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
panel3.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel3, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
panel3 .setMinimumSize(...); panel3 .setMaximumSize(...) ; panel3 .setPreferredSize(...);

JTextField tf1 = new JTextField("text_field_1");
tf1.setMinimumSize(...); tf1.setMaximumSize(...) ; tf1.setPreferredSize(...);

panel2.add(tf1);
panel.add(panel2);
panel.add(panel3);
panel.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
panel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(...)));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly possible with NetBeans.

But, there are three things you have to know to work with Matisse (the Swing designer in NetBeans):

1. To make a container fit around its content, you have to resize the container, until it snaps to the content.
2. To make the content follow the size of the container, you have to resize the content, until it snaps the the border of the container.
3. You can always manually configure the auto-resizing behavior of a component by right clicking the component and choose what you want under the *Auto-Resizing* submenu.